# Command Prompt error while trying to reindex a Magento installation

Tags: php, magento

I'm reading a book about the Magento 2 system. I get an error when I run this command:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\packt\bin>php magento indexer:info
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower() in C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php:56
>
> Stack trace:
>   0 C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\var\generation\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('core_collection...', Array)
>   1 C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php(531): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('core_collection...', Array)
>   2 C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(562): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->_beforeLoad()
>   3 C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(550): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
>   4 C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(333): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
>   5 C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\modul in C:\xampp\htdocs\packt\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php on line 56

Answer (score 0):

looks like you don't have mb_string extension in php.

to enable extension just uncomment follow line in your php.ini

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

Comment: appreciate your feedback, but I did this prior to this error as I found someone with a similar problem. It didn't work. But maybe I edited the wrong php.ini? I downloaded and placed the php 7 in my C:\php, but I also have a folder called php in Xampp, do they conflict? **Apparantly after a night of sleep I tried to use the "shell" from the Xampp interface and that worked**